# Why do I keep getting an error code when I'm trying to run the query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

syntax error in query expression
SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE
[Type]=5 And Left([Name],1)<>”~” ORDER BY [Name];
[image]

Comment: I copy/pasted your SQL and it errors because of the quote marks. I deleted and retyped them and it works. Or use apostrophes.

Comment: Those quotes are _smart quotes_ from Word. But SQL isn't smart enough to read them as quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your double quote char is invalid. Not sure what character you are using, but you can use double quotes

```
SELECT [Name] 
FROM MSysObjects 
WHERE [Type]=5 AND LEFT([Name],1)<>"~" 
ORDER BY [Name];
```

or apostrophes

```
SELECT [Name] 
    FROM MSysObjects 
    WHERE [Type]=5 AND LEFT([Name],1)<>'~' 
    ORDER BY [Name];
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your query then replaced apostrophes with quotes and it works.

Comment: You're right! the OP has strange double quotes in the query. Nice catch! I guess I assumed I was right be the query worked but that I see the OPs double quotes I see the issue.

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.